# org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.create.setProperties` registered for this database instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, aws-fargate, neo4j-apoc, amazon-efs

I am trying to setup Neo4j community edition on AWS Fargate, and for Volumes, I am using EFS.
but when I added Volume in task definition it gives me this error

org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.create.setProperties` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.create.setProperties` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Note: If I remove the volumes from task defination then service will run without any issue.

Comment: Do you have the apoc plugin installed?

Comment: Yes I have apoc plugin installed, having issue only when I tried to add EFS volume with Neo4j FARGATE container. without Volume it works very well